# jquery doesnt position element properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jquery experiment in which there is an div with id="mask" to be positioned in the center of the page.
i have tried both

Jquery:

```
$("#mask").height()
```

and javascript's native:

```
var mask = document.getElementById("mask");
var ht_mask = getComputedStyle(mask).getPropertyValue("height");
var ht_mask_num = Number(ht_mask.slice(0,ht_mask.length - 2));
```

both give different values on console.log() in firefox and chrome
i have the experiment on

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avi_sagi/3RAEE/embedded/result/

and on my website(sometimes works well) : http://sagiavinash.com/projects/labs/Holi/

luckily it works for some people but if they reload multiple times it doesnt work all the times. 
i checked the Chrome network tab in inspect element which gives information abt the order of loading of resources i see jquery not loading sometimes even though i use google CDN which is the best.this is not completely a reason to the misplacement but a factor

FYI: i use "meyer reset css" and "jquery 1.11.0"
this is one problem i detected there might be other issues responsible for this positioning problem.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
$("#mask").css('marginTop', margin_top + "px");
```

With

```
$("#mask").css('position', "absolute",'top','20%');
```

Hope It helps

Comment: no because its not pixel perfect
this can be a cover up i find it hard to digest that i couldnt find a solution to simple jquery concepts